# How to debug django staticfiles served with whitenoise, gunicorn, and heroku?

Tags: python, django, docker, heroku, gunicorn

I've got a project that runs on Heroku from a Dockerfile and heroku.yml.

The site generally works, but I am having trouble with static files.

`collectstatic` is run when building the pack.

If I set `DEBUG` to True, it finds the files.

I'm trying to use whitenoise but not sure why it's not working. It sounds so simple so I'm sure it's something silly.

heroku.yml

```
setup:
    addons:
        - plan: heroku-postgresql
build:
    docker:
        web: Dockerfile
release:
    image: web
    command:
        - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
run:
    web: gunicorn records_project.wsgi
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware',
]
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    ... more stuff here...
```

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
# for referencing files with a URL
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# where to find static files when local
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
# location of satatic files for production
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
# how Django should look for static file directories; below is default
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    # defaults
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
# This gives me a 500 error
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns here...
...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I never found a way to get WhiteNoise to serve those static files. I swear it's worked in the past with a similar set up, so that will remain a mystery.

I received a tip from Matt from justdjango.com that Heroku doesn't want to serve static files from that same server. Once I moved my static files over to an AWS S3 bucket, all was well.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you are referencing a static file (e.g., a CSS file or image) in your template that doesn't exist? I was having this same problem because I had the following in my base template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
```

But no styles.css file in my css folder.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't THINK that's the case, but maybe I'm wrong. Here's what I know with an example:

These are both in my `<head>`...

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/base.css">`

The first loads well. The second gives me errors in the console: 
`Refused to apply style from 'https://subdomain.domain.com/static/css/base.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Comment: And sorry, to directly answer you: I have those files and it is unable to load the stylesheets in the admin.

Comment: `/static/css/base.css` is probably the issue. Try using `{% static 'css/base.css' %}` in your template. You will also need to include `{% load static %}` at the top of the template.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I am already using `{% load static %}` at the top of my template and using `{% static 'css/base.css' %}` to render the link to that CSS file. `/static/css/base.css` is what the template renders in the browser.

Comment: I see you have `STATICFILES_STORAGE` commented out. I think you need that. I was getting a 500 error too. A missing or mis-referenced static file will cause a 500 error. If it's not that, I don't know what it could be. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue because static files, collected on release stage, were missing on run. So i changed my code to:

**heroku.yml**

```
setup:
  addons:
    - plan: heroku-postgresql
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - chmod u+x entrypoint_heroku.sh
run:
  web: ./entrypoint_heroku.sh
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y netcat

RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile* /usr/src/app/
RUN pipenv install --system --dev

COPY . /usr/src/app/

RUN mkdir -p /storage/static/
```

**entrypoint_heroku.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py migrate --noinput
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
gunicorn app.wsgi
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/storage/'
STATIC_ROOT = MEDIA_ROOT + 'static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Not the best solution. But it helped me to run server with Debug=False

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try this out when I get a chance.

Comment: Weird. I'm getting a permission denied error when it tries to run `entrypoint_heroku.sh` even with the chmod command.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. Although **successfully collecting** static files on release stage, they weren't present when dyno was up (thus Django missing manifest errors).

This setup worked:

**heroku.yml**

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: ./heroku_entrypoint.sh
```

**Dockerfile**

```
--- some code ---

RUN chmod +x heroku_entrypoint.sh
RUN mkdir -p /app/static/

--- other code ---
```

**heroku_entrypoint.sh**

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py migrate
gunicorn app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```